# How can I make these TypeScript types support arrays?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type Definition<SuperDef extends string, Attributes extends string[]> = {
  superDef: SuperDef;
  attributes: Attributes;
}

interface Definitions {
  'foo': Definition<'', ['a']>;
  'bar': Definition<'foo', ['b']>;
  'baz': Definition<'bar', ['c']>;
}

type SuperDef<Name extends keyof Definitions> = Definitions[Name]['superDef'];
type Attributes<Name extends keyof Definitions> = Definitions[Name]['attributes'];

type AllAttributes<Name extends keyof Definitions> =
    Name extends keyof Definitions
        ? SuperDef<Name> extends keyof Definitions
            ? [...AllAttributes<SuperDef<Name>>, ...Attributes<Name>]
            : Attributes<Name>
        : never;

type AnyAttribute<Name extends keyof Definitions> = AllAttributes<Name>[number];

// AllAttributes<'baz'> = ['a', 'b', 'c']
// AnyAttribute<'baz'> = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

My goal is to change `SuperDef` to an array of strings. Might as well change it to `extends (keyof Definitions)[]` to avoid unnecessary `Name extends keyof Definitions` checks. Here is what the head of the code would look like:

```js
type Definition<SuperDefs extends (keyof Definitions)[], Attributes extends string[]> = {
  superDefs: SuperDefs;
  attributes: Attributes;
}

interface Definitions {
  'foo': Definition<[], ['a']>;
  'bar': Definition<['foo'], ['b']>;
  'baz': Definition<['foo'], ['c']>;
  'qux': Definition<['bar', 'baz'], ['d']>;
}

// AllAttributes<'baz'> = ['a', 'c']
// AnyAttribute<'baz'> = 'a' | 'c'
// AllAttributes<'qux'> = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
// AnyAttribute<'qux'> = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
```

How would I write `AllAttributes` and `AnyAttribute`? I understand that having `AllAttributes` complicates things because it requires that the compiler understand the order of values in the array. Ideally, I would want both, where `AnyAttribute` uses `AllAttributes`, but mainly looking for `AnyAttribute`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tsplay.dev/NdaLdm
`AnyAttribute` requires fixing the `[]` case to not work incorrectly, otherwise it's pretty straightforward

```
type AnyAttribute<K extends keyof Definitions> =
  | Definitions[K] extends Definition<infer SD, infer A> ? (
    A[number] | (SD extends [] ? never : AnyAttribute<SD[number]>)
  )
  : never
```

https://tsplay.dev/NdaLdm
`AllAttributes` requires a much harder algorithm, in JS it would be:

```
function AllAttributes(key) {
  let a = Definitions[key];
  return unique([
    ...a.superDef.map(k => AllAttributes(k)).flat(),
    ...a.attributes // last so deep attrs go first
  ])
}
function unique(list) { return [...new Set(list)]; }
```

which in types would look like

```
type AllAttributes<K extends keyof Definitions> =
  | Definitions[K] extends Definition<infer SD, infer A>
  ? (
    SD extends [] ? A :
    Unique<[...Flat<{ [K in keyof SD]: AllAttributes<SD[K]> }>, ...A]>
  )
  : never

type Flat<A extends any[]> =
  | A extends [infer F extends any[], ...infer L extends any[]]
  ? (
    [...F, ...Flat<L>]
  )
  : []

type Unique<A extends any[], X = never> =
  | A extends [infer F, ...infer L]
  ? (
    F extends X ? Unique<L, X>
    : [F, ...Unique<L, X | F>]
  )
  : []
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your approach of writing the type as a JS function.

Comment: Why not derive `AnyAttribute` from `AllAttributes` with `AllAttributes<K>[number]`?

Comment: @Oliver because I chose to write it first as it was more simple (and because it's much more performant this way, but you won't notice that unleast you have 100s of attributes at once)

Comment: @Oliver but yes it would be more correct, as `AnyAttribute<never>` fails to `string` atm

Comment: Ah, and none of them supports `AnyAttribute<keyof Definitions>` lol

Comment: At least they support `AnyAttribute<'one' | 'two'>`.